# Disqus Data Synchronization with PHP API

Tags: php, disqus

http://docs.disqus.com/help/58/

Can someone show be howto get that working? I'm not sure I understand how to use the code shown in a real life context.

I've created a database and have downloaded the PHP API, but im not sure howto use it even with the documentation linked above.

I presume to save and check for the posts at regular intervals I'll need to use CRON, but I should be able to get that myself if I can figure out howto work with the API.

Thanks

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Missing required argument: forum'
```

^^ That's the error I get when I try to make it work with the most basic example below:

```
$DisqusAPI = new DisqusAPI('my_api_key');

// query our MAX datestamp
$since = "SELECT MAX(nDA) FROM news";

$params = array('forum'=>'my_forum_name','since'=>(int)$since,'limit'=>100);

// fetch newer than posts from API
$posts = $DisqusAPI->forums->listPosts(json_decode($params));

// save posts locally
foreach ($posts as $post) {
   //save($post);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically what they're saying is you need to create a database table (or some other datastore) to hold comments you download from Disqus to your site.  They provide a recommended schema for a database table.

You would then use their API client (the one you downloaded) to pull down the comments, loop over them and store them in your database.  They give you guidelines to make sure the interaction is lean by not downloading all the comments at once, and only downloading ones you may not have downloaded yet.

You might want to download the Wordpress plugin and read through it for a complete practical application using the client.

Comment: I take it you didn't read my question completely? But I shall have another browse through the WP docs..

Comment: @Ezra, can you share your db schema for the comments and tell us what interface/library you're using to interact with the database?  I think I can draw up an example with that info.

Comment: Again, read the question, the db is setup exactly as specified in the Disqus docs and im using the Disqus PHP API lib linked from the documentation in the link at the start of the question. That is this one: https://github.com/disqus/disqus-php

Comment: Yes, the only difference then from the example would be your db layer.  Basically with the example code all you need to change is the interaction w/ the database for your library and you should be golden.

Comment: Where would this example be? And wheres the documentation for this example?

Comment: I keep getting fatal errors with it, hence the need for a 'working' example

Answer (score 0):

In the example in there, they're sending the data as a JSON object. You're sending it as an `array`. Do you think that might be the problem?

Comment: Hmm, perhapes :P. Doing it that way gives me (if you directly copy paste their example) 'Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{', expecting ')'

Comment: Try your `$params` variable, but `json_encode()` it before sending, so : `$posts = $DisqusAPI->forums->listPosts(json_encode($params));`

Comment: One step foward and another back, now I get: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Missing required argument: forum'

Answer (score 0):

Well, the problem is that the code is assigning an incorrect data type to an `Exception` property.  After taking a brief look through the DisqusAPI on github I believe I have [found your offending line of code](https://github.com/disqus/disqus-php/blob/master/disqusapi/disqusapi.php#L115).

From your error message it appears that `$data->code` or `$data->response` is not a valid type, possibly being an `array` or an `object`.  Based on your example, the error message and the DisqusAPI code this appears to be the likely culprit.

Comment: Take a look at the answer by Indranil and the comments below it. I've gotten past that particular issue, but ran into another.